# Is an open connected set "grid connected?"

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open connected set. This implies that it the set is polygon connected. That means, given $a,b\in S$, there is a finite sequence of line segments $[a,a_1],[a_1,a_2],...,[a_{n-1},b]$ which are all contained in $S$.

But is it "grid connected?" (I'm inventing this terminology on the spot, so bear with me.) I define a set $E\subseteq \mathbb C$ to be "grid connected" if, given points $a,b\in E$, there is a finite sequence of line segments $[a,a_1],[a_1,a_2],...,[a_{n-1},b]$ **each of which is either horizontal or vertical**.

For example, the plane $\mathbb C$ is "grid connected" because, given distinct points $a+bi$ and $c+di$, we can connect them with the line segments $[a+bi, c+bi]$ and $[c+bi,c+di]$. (i.e. with a horizontal line segment and a vertical line segment.

[image]

Comment: What proof do you know of the fact that open connected sets on the plane are "polygon connected"? It will probably be adaptable to show that they are "grid connected" as well. (For instance, the proof by defining an equivalence relation given by $x \sim y$ if $x$ can reach $y$ applies *mutatis mutandis*.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you agree that we can connect using line segments, it suffices to prove that for each segment $[z,w]$ there are a finite number of vertical or horizontal segments $[a_1,a_2]$, $[a_2,a_3]$, ... $[a_{k-1}, a_k]$, contained in the original set $S$ such that $a_1 = z$ and $a_k = w$.

Since $z\in S$ and $S$ is open, there is an open neighborhood of $z$ contained in $S$. There we can connect with horizontal and vertical lines as shown in the picture, and, importantly, we're still in $S$.

[image: Proof with an image]

Finally, since $[z,w]$ is compact, only finitely many of those neighborhoods are needed.